# matching multiple parts of string with wildcards added

Tags: python, regex, string, wildcard, python-re

What I want with python to match a string with a substring, in the substring there are wildcards added, I tried this without luck, it works only without wildcards added in the `Bstring` and is exactly the same as the `Astring`:

```py
import re
Astring = ['123.456.789.10.11.12.abc']
Bstring = ['*.456.789.*.11.12.*']
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
if re.findall(Astring, Bstring)):
    # (do something)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it(assuming you have two equal length lists, one for actual strings, one for wildcards):

```py
import re

Astring = ["123.456.789.10.11.12.abc"]
Bstring = ["*.456.789.*.11.12.*"]

for string, pattern in zip(Astring, Bstring):
    pattern = pattern.replace(".", r"\.").replace("*", ".*")
    print(pattern)
    if re.fullmatch(pattern, string):
        print("It's OK")
```

output:

```
.*\.456\.789\..*\.11\.12\..*
It's OK
```

I had to first escape every dots into `\.` to match exactly a "dot" not "any character". Then I changed `*` to `.*` because `.*` means any character with any number of occurrences(start from zero).

---

Another simple way is using [`fnmath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch):

```py
from fnmatch import fnmatch

Astring = ["123.456.789.10.11.12.abc"]
Bstring = ["*.456.789.*.11.12.*"]

for string, pattern in zip(Astring, Bstring):
    if fnmatch(string, pattern):
        print("It's OK")
```